# tar directory contains ._ files

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tar

I extracted files from a tar directory and noticed that on my mac for each file there was also another file named `._<filename>`. I did the standard procedure with:

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('file.tar.gz', 'r:gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall()
```

The files contain something like:
`Mac OS X            2PATTRP���Acom.apple.qua....`

Can I get rid of those before extracting somehow? Or would I have to check if the file starts with `._` before doing so?